# How do you debug deploy error in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've create the simplest project from the new project wizard. It compiles just fine but fails deploying. How can I find why? Is there a more comprhensive window or place where I can find the actual reason? The only message I get is a simple failure from Visual Studio 2015.

```
`
1>------ Build started: Project: App2, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  App2 -> c:\users\testuser\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App2\App2\bin\x86\Debug\App2.exe
2>------ Deploy started: Project: App2, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
`
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, navigate to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity: and set it to "Diagnostic". Let me know what the new output says for the deployment failure.

Comment: Hi. Did you happen to resolve the issue? I'v got the same behavior on one of the developer machines.

Comment: As a matter of fact I did. I recall it had something to do with Nuget and dependencies on the target machine. I remember fooling around forcing installation of the dependencies and at some point it worked. Sorry, for not having anything more precise. I'm actually working on something related, I'll let you know if I find the solution again.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Configuration Manager under the Build tab.
2. Click *Any CPU* dropdown (Next to *Debug*) in VS.
3. Navigate to *Build* tab and you will see *Configuration manager* as the last option.
4. check *Deploy* option.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote; that worked for me -- a little more descriptive [here](https://onestopdotnet.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/xamarin-vs-2015-break-the-error-message-into-chunks/).

Answer (score -2):

I experienced the following error while Debugging.Kindly help us if you could.

The project blinkyCpp needs to be deploy before it can be started

verify the project is selected to be deployed in the solution configuration manager, or deploy it explicitly by clicking on the deploy command in the build menu